# Is it possible to run ILMerge at compile time within SharpDevelop?

Tags: build-process, build-automation, ilmerge, sharpdevelop

I'd like to offer my .Net library (which I'm developing in the [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) IDE) as a single dll.  I've been manually using [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en) to merge my compiled library and all its reference libraries together, but would like this done automatically.

I'd ideally like to have this automatic merge happen from within SharpDevelop, without having to set up an external build script.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharpDevelop uses MSBuild to compile your code so the simplest way would be to create a [post build step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293582.aspx) that runs ILMerge with the correct parameters. You can create a post build step from the Project Options under the Build Events tab. Alternatively you can directly edit your project file in Notepad.